# How can I see what IP address my iPhone, iPod touch, or iPad has?

Tags: network, internet

I would like to know what IP-address my iPhone, iPod touch, or iPad has. E.g. if I use my iPhone, iPod touch or iPad over WiFi, how can I get the local IP-address that is assigned to my iPhone, iPod touch, or iPad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IP address is shown in Settings -> WiFi -> Info icon at end of (Name of network):

[image]

Comment: As a subtle point to nohillside's answer, the English (US) localization uses Settings > WiFi, then tap the little, blue, encircled 'i' on the right edge after the current network name. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

There are two potential solutions to getting your IP: a Shortcut and An App.

#### Shortcut

I created a simple shortcut called [Get IP Addresses](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/2be133805f9e4d18a8aba34949af8ee9).  It was tested on iPad running iPadOS 16 and iPhone 12 running 16.1.2. It will output both your Local and External IP addresses.

[image: Get IP Addresses Screen Grab]

#### System Status App

There is a simple App (free) called *[System Status](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/system-status-hw-monitor/id407752428)*.

It gives a full view of your hardware from battery to CPU and of course, network.  What I like is that all the info is right there on the main screen including private (internal) IP, external IP, gateway, DNS and SSID.  Here’s a sample screen grab (redacted my external IP).

[image: System Status screen capture]

Since I am always diagnosing someone’s network, this app give me a single tap access to the info I’m looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Or from your Mac you could try to list all devices in your local network with a little tool, for example https://angryip.org which is free & OpenSource.

Next to each IP Adresses there is the associated host name device (for example "iPhone of Elon Musk")